My multi-process program runs slower than a single process
I need to convert each subgraph into a matrix, take the corresponding point to calculate the nearest 1 distance. My code logic is to first construct a large dict by obtaining the subgraph matrix and then the distance obtained from the points of this subgraph.
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager,get_context,Lock
lock = Lock()
def get_distances(key,values,finally_dict):
    local_idx = eval(key.split('_')[1].split('.')[0])
    clip_num =  int(key.split('_')[0][-1])
    x1 = local_idx[0]
    x2 = local_idx[1]
    judge_x = 0 + 880
    judge_y = 0 + 880
    if clip_num == 1:
        x1 += 1000 * 100 - judge_x
        x2 += 1000 * 100 - judge_y
    elif clip_num == 2:
        x1 += 1000 * 400 - judge_x
        x2 += 1000 * 700 - judge_y
    else:
        x1 += 1000 * 800 - judge_x
        x2 += 1000 * 1300 - judge_y
    size_2048 = 0
    # 获取该图片的左下角位置
    current_x, current_y = x1+size_2048, x2+size_2048
    photo_idx = data_list.index(key)
    # photo_matrix = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join('/data/New_EXP_0805/Without_DownSample_data_withourdummy_2560_DOINN', f'DOINN_resist_{photo_idx+1}.png')).crop((256, 256, 256 + 2048, 256 + 2048)))/255
    photo_matrix = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join('/data/New_EXP_0805/Without_DownSample_data_withourdummy_2560_DOINN', f'DOINN_resist_{photo_idx+1}.png')))/255
    # if 
    if len(values) != 0:
        for point in values:
            # for point in polygen:
                # if point[0][0] == 988 and point[0][1] == 40:
                #     print('now') print(entry[1][0]+int(key.split(',')[1][:-1]),entry[1][1]+2048-int(key.split(',')[0][1:]))
            new_idx = (2048-(point[0][1]-local_idx[1]),point[0][0]-local_idx[0])
            disst =get_distence_corner_2560(photo_matrix,new_idx,point[1],step_length_metric)
            with lock:
                if point[-1 ]  != 'corner':
                    finally_dict['no_corner'][repr(point[0])] =  [key,(current_x+point[0][1]), current_y+2048-point[0][0],disst,point[1]]
                    # finally_dict['no_corner'][repr(point[0])] =  [key,(current_x, current_y),get_distence(photo_matrix,point[0],point[1]),point[1]]
                else:
                    finally_dict['is_corner'][repr(point[0])] =  [key,(current_x+point[0][1]), current_y+2048-point[0][0],disst,point[1]]
    return 1
def print_error(value):
    print("error:", value)

def update_progress(result, pbar):
    pbar.update(result)  # 更新进度条
thread_num = 32
# 使用 Manager 创建进程安全的字典
with Manager() as manager:
    # photo_poly = manager.dict()  # 创建进程安全的字典
    finally_dict = manager.dict()
    finally_dict['is_corner'] = manager.dict()
    finally_dict['no_corner'] = manager.dict()
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(contour_point_dict)) as pbar:
        # idx_0 = 0
        with Pool(processes=thread_num) as pool:
            for key,values in tqdm.tqdm(contour_point_dict.items()):
                # get_distances(key,values,finally_dict)
                pool.apply_async(get_distances, args=(key,values,finally_dict), callback=lambda result: update_progress(result, pbar),
                                    error_callback=print_error)
                # idx_0 += 1
                # pbar.update(1)

            pool.close()
            pool.join()  # 等待所有进程完成 
    finally_dict['is_corner'] = dict(finally_dict['is_corner'])
    finally_dict['no_corner'] = dict(finally_dict['no_corner'])
    finally_dict = dict(finally_dict)

It takes 6 hours while my single process only takes 4 hours.
contour_point_dict contains the name of the subgraph and a series of distances to be obtained. Finally I want to save all the points of his distance information.

Multiprocessing has overhead. Except for programs where the benefits overwhelm that overhead this is completely normal; doubly so with numpy since it can do its own parallelization so when you add multiprocessing on top you're paying context switch overhead for no benefit. Don't try to use multiprocessing until and unless you understand how and why it works and what costs it incurs.
